# How to check if user is already signed in via gmail or google account?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
                if(!em.isEmpty() || !pass.isEmpty()) {
                    mfirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(em, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            } else {
                                String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();

                                switch (errorCode) {

                                    case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "The email address is badly formatted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        email.setError("The email address is badly formatted.");
                                        email.requestFocus();
                                        break;


                                    case "ERROR_USER_MISMATCH":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using associated email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "The email address is already in use by another account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        email.requestFocus();
                                        break;

                                    case "ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "This credential is already associated with a different user account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "The user account has been disabled by an administrator.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case "ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "The user\\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginActivity.this, "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        password.setError("password is incorrect ");
                                        password.requestFocus();
                                        password.setText("");
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

**The Problem I am facing is:**

The user first signup using 'signup with email'. After that the user signup with a Google account(With the same email).

Now after that when the user tries to login via email and password. I get the error that the password is incorrect, I know this happens because sign up with email details has been overwritten by Google account details.

I want to show the error "The email is linked with google account. Please login via google account".

Comment: try linking google account with email&Password acoount. check the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Comment: Thank you.......

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AuthCredential`  and `isNewUser` Here is the example

```
 private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
            if (isNewUser) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Is New User!");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                //do something
                //You can call register class or function here


            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "Is Old User!");
                //Do something else


            }
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know if a user is signed in with Google or email and password, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
List<? extends UserInfo> userInfoList = firebaseUser.getProviderData();
for (UserInfo userInfo : userInfoList) {
    String providerId = userInfo.getProviderId();
    if (providerId.equals(GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
        //Do stuff
    } else if (providerId.equals("password")) {
        //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

So you can take some action according to the way the user is signed in.